# Reshaping numpy array as an input to CNN

Tags: machine-learning, keras, input, conv-neural-network

I have seen multiple posts on reshaping numpy arrays as inputs to CNN's however, I haven't been able to successfully reshape my array as an input to my CNN!

I have a CNN that merges with another model further downstream. The input shape of the CNN is `(4,4,1)` -- it is bigger but i have purposefully made it smaller to establish he pipeline and get it running before i put in the proper size.

the format will be the same however, its a 1 channel n x n np.array. I am getting errors when reshaping which I will mention after the code. The input dimensions are put in to the model as follows:

```
cnn_branch_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,4,1))
cnn_branch_two = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(etc....)(cnn_branch_input)
```

the np array (which is originally a pandas dataframe) characteristics and reshaping are as follows:

```
np.array(array).shape
(4,4)

input = np.array(array).reshape(-1,1,4,4)
input.shape
(1,1,4,4)
```

the input to my merged model is as follows:

```
model.fit([cnn_input,gnn_input, gnn_node_feat], y,
    #sample_weight=train_mask,
    #validation_data=validation_data,
    batch_size=4,
    shuffle=False)
```

this causes an error which makes sense to me:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 1, 4, 4 -- Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

So now when reshaping to intentionally have a 4x4 plus 1 channel shape as follows:
input = np.array(array).reshape(-1,4,4,1)
input.shape
(1,4,4,1)

Two things, the array reshapes to 4, 1x1 arrays, so it seems the structure of the original array is lost, and I get the same error!!

Notice that in both reshape methods, the shape is either `(1,4,4,1) or (1,1,4,4)`.. the -1 entry simply becomes a 1, making the CNN think the first element is shape 1. I thought the -1 would allow me to successfully add the sample dimension as 'any number of samples'.

Simply entering the original `(4,4)` array, I receive the error that the CNN received a 2 dim array while a 4 dimension array is required.

Im really confused as to how to correctly reshape this array! I would appreciate any help!

Comment: As far as I recall, the first dimension is the number of samples. (n, 4, 4, 1)

Comment: So your target shape is (4,4,1) and you are reshaping to (1,4,4) ? How exactly is it supposed to work?

Comment: so i have also rehaped to 4,4,1 but with the '-1' dimension in order to specify any sample size, but this -1 translates in to a 1. even when reshaping to 4,4,1 without specifying the -1 as sample size i get an error that the expected input ndim 4, but ndim 3 was provided. hence the -1... but this becomes a 1.. it is this particular problem i am requiring assistance with